# How to call db.eval() via mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some functions saved in MongoDB Server.
Is there some methods to call them, like the native call db.eval().

May be like this (I Tried， not work)：

```
mongoose.connection.db.eval("Foo('Arg1','Arg2')", function(err, retVal) {
    // the eval result
});
```

or this (not work either):

```
mongoose.connection.db.eval("Foo", ['Arg1','Arg2'], function(err, retVal) {
    // the eval result
});
```

The `callback` function was never called.
And the return of `mongoose.connection.db.eval` was `undefine`.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
mongoose.connection.db.eval('function(foo) {return foo;}', 'bar', {}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: This is the client function.