# how to use mongo db.eval through Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

From my mongo shell I can run functions with `db.eval` like:

```
db.eval('return 7;');
```

And, but for a deprecation warning, the parameter function is run properly.

Now I want to call such a 'script' from `node.js`, through `mongoose`.

I've tried to just call `db.eval` with the stringified function code as parameter (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768588/called-a-stored-javascript-function-from-mongoose)):

```
mongoose.connect(PATH_TO_A_MONGO_DATABASE);
mongoose.connection.db.eval('return 9;', function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
    //etc.
});
```

This silently ignores the callback. No error is thrown, and the callback function is never called.

When doing this, I checked that `mongoose.connection.db.eval` is actually a function.

Since `db.eval` also has a Promise interface, also tried:

```
mongoose.connection.db.eval('return 5;').then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

With the same result: no errors, just silence.

So, I guess I'm missing something with the syntax, but I can't find documentation or examples about this. Any similar questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641059/how-to-call-db-eval-via-mongoose) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969372/execute-mongo-function-through-mongoose-lib) didn't help.

PD1: I'm willing to do this because I need to call a procedure stored in `system.js` through `mongoose`. I can't do that too. However, I can't even run a silly script like `return 5;`, so I'm asking for the simpler task before. Any advice on how to call server scripts with mongoose is welcome.

PD2: I'm aware stored server scripts in mongo are a bad practice, and that they are deprecated for a reason and so on... but I can't  just decide about that. I've been told to do that at my company, and the co-worker who set up the original code of the stored server script is not here now.

Comment: Eval is deprecated ( marked from v3.0.0 ). Which means DO NOT USE IT. Because even if it is not gone yet, it **IS** going. And when it's gone your code will simply not work. You don't need serverside JavaScript execution anyway. It's simply the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out why my `db.eval` callbacks was being ignored. It is related with the mongoose connection.

If you start a connection like:

```
const conn = mongoose.connect(PATH_TO_DB);
```

And then just make a query:

```
conn.model(a_collection, a_schema).find({}).exec().then()...
```

Even if you just call the query right after the connection -it is, logically, an asynchronous process-, mongooose figures that it has to wait to the connection to be in a proper state, then fire the query, then call the callback with the query results.

However, this doesn't work the same way with `db.eval()`. just trying to call `db.eval()` right after the call to the connection, the callback is silently ignored:

```
const conn = mongoose.connect(PATH_TO_DB);
conn.db.eval('return 5;', (err, response) => {
    //nothing happends
})
```

That was the way I was creating the connection and calling `db.eval`, so I couldn't get `db.eval()` to work.

In order to fire a `db.eval` and make it work, it seems that you need to wait for the connection explicitly:

```
const conn = mongoose.connect(PATH_TO_DB, err => {
    mongoose.connection.db.eval('return 5', (err, result) => {
         result; //5!
    })
});
```

To make a query before any attemps to call `db.eval` also works:

```
const conn = mongoose.connect(PATH_TO_DB);
conn.model(a_collection, a_schema).find({}).exec()
.then(() => {
    conn.db.eval('return 5', (err, result) => {
         result; //5!
    })
})
```